# Snap scaling doesn't behave like expected

Tags: scale, snapping

For some reason I can't snap to a specific point.

I want to snap the orange line (with scaling) from the first image, to the line below it.
But as you can see in image 2 it scales way too wide.

I think I have searched every forum, but couldn't find an answer that helped.

Hope one of you can help me :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please show your snap settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t worry, it works.

1) Enable snapping to vertex
2) When using a scale tool *grab a vertex* of your circle to scale it. *Grabbing the scale tool ring won’t work*.
3) The vertex you’re holding is now snapping to other vertices.

*Enable snapping to vertex*
[image: Enable snapping to vertex]

*Grab a vertex, not the scale tool ring*
[image]

*Moving the vertex now scales the object and snaps to other vertices*
[image]

Hope this helps.
If you need any clarification, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I also found another mistake I made, I didn't press shift z, so that it won't scale on the z axis. For some reason that also helped, even though I was in top view