# Snapping to vertex when scaling (Blender 2.8)

Tags: modeling

Snapping to a vertex doesn't seem to work for me. The pivot point is set to median point, and I have enabled scaling under snapping options. I don't understand why blender doesn't scale the shape to exactly the size of the circle I've selected.

Note that the "circle" I am trying to scale is not a perfect circle, since I messed it up previously due to the mirror modifier. However, also note that this ellipse was previously scaled down from the circle I'm trying to snap to, which is why I'm trying to scale it back to its original size.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). There was a similar question some time ago, perhaps it could help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/156712

Comment: I'm sorry, it didn't work. I tried scaling in z, then x axes too.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but it solves your problem much more easily. Use edge slide. Just tap G twice and slide the edge up into place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snap scale to vertex tool can be a bit finicky, so here are a bunch of things to try. Basically, any time the vertex you're snapping two doesn't perfectly line up, the snapping is way off.

I don't know your exact set up, but I would be cautious about using Median as the pivot point with a mirror modifier. The Median pivot point doesn't take into the mirror geometry, so you might not be scaling from the right point:

[image]

I almost always use the 3D cursor as the pivot point. It can be a little more tedious, but you have much finer control. Select two vertices on opposite sides of the circle and move the 3D cursor to selected.

[image]

Then, set your snapping element to 'Active' in the snap settings, and make sure you're targeting the right vertex. You can see below when I initially am snapping to the wrong vertex, it overscales my selection.

[image]

Comment: I guess I should be avoiding the problem in the first place. Since I scaled it down using median point(which is wrong), I was curious if I could undo what I did by scaling it up from median point again. But I guess it doesn't work after all. I'll try vertex sliding then. I've read that I can set the direction of transformation manually so that I can actually snap to vertex.