# Scale an edge loop to match another

Tags: scale, snapping, loop

I were trying to scale edge loop A so it would be the same size as edge loop B:

[image]

Intuitively I scaled and snapped like this:

[image]

But now A is slightly bigger than B.

My snapping settings and pivot point look like:

[image]

I fiddled with these settings for a while but couldn't get it right. I looked up LoopTools but it seems to for more complicated operations. Is there a simple way to make A just as big as B?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/156712/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure you are constraining the scale to the X/Y axis. For that, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> after <kbd>s</kbd>.

[image]